# access the file system

Tags: android, android-file

I put my files in the directory assets. how do I get them?
I tried following the instructions but have not worked:

```
File f = new File("/data/data/ant.BrowserX/files/" + pagCorrente + ".html");

File f = new File("file:///android_asset/" + pagCorrente + ".html");
```

there are no errors but running I can not access the file. How do I access the directory "assets"?

EDIT

thanks for the trick. I have the problem that I use a BufferedReader to read the file, and initialize it so, and not with an InputStream.

```
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
```

how could I do?

Comment: the "/data/data" directory is only accessible on rooted devices and apps that work with root permissions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you can use this to get a inputstream :

```
  final AssetManager assetMgr = this.getResources().getAssets();  
  InputStream is = assetMgr.open(pagCorrente +".html");
```

So probably you can use:

```
   File f = new File(this.getResources().getAssets() + pagCorrente + ".html");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get an InputStream from the file through the getAssets() method inside getResources():

```
 InputStream is = getResources().getAssets().open("file.html");
```

Then just convert the stream to whatever you need

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, you don't access the "directory" assets.  There is no directory structure in an .apk, it's just data.  The framework knows how to access it (`getAssets()`), but you can't use it like a standard directory.

That being said, if you are trying to use a WebView and access a html file (which is what it looks like) they put a "fake" path reference in that you can use like this:

```
WebView wv = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.yourWebView); 
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + pagCorrente + ".html");
```